# Dynamically setting values for grand total price - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem lies with the `<legend class="final" >Total Order $: <span></span></legend>`
  which displays my grand sum. What happens is, when I key up a digit figure like `1 or 2 or 3` in the quantity text box, it adds up accurately

but then when I type `12` (two-digit) it doesn't give me accurate results and when also clear the quantity box, nothing the grand sum doesn't move to the previous figure it was but rather, it stays the same.

PS: Sorry for my bad english and a JS beginner

**HTML**

```
<input onclick="return checkout(this)" type="checkbox" /> 
<legend class="final" >Total Order $: <span></span></legend> 

<div class="panel" id="panel"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkout(data)
  { 
    if(data.checked == true) {
      $('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container"> ' +    
        '<p class="name"> Item: ' + data.name + '</p>' +
        '<p class="price" data-price="' + data.price + '">Price : ' + data.price + '</p>'+
        '<input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity[]" /><br><br>' +
        '<p class="total" >Total Price  $:<span name="total" id="total"></span></p>' +
        '</div>'
      ).appendTo('form');
    }
    else {
      $(".panel .container [data-id=" + data.id + "]").parent().remove();  
    }
}

$('.panel').on('keyup','.quantity',function()
  {
    var container = $(this).closest('div');
    var quantity = Number($(this).val());
    var price = 
    Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    

    container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);

    sum += quantity*price;

    console.log('Grand Cost ' +sum);

    $('.final span').text(sum);

  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for us?

Comment: @Dumisani, i am new with fiddle as well but i tried creating one and it wasn't working for me. Maybe it wasn't generic enough

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsm6d4zp/

Comment: @chade. thank you.. i will update my html to point out the issue

Comment: I think we need more code. Like what calls the `checkout` function

Comment: @chade_ i have updated my html with the checkbox that calls the `checkout`. i receive json from every item  i select

Comment: @Dumisani i have updated my code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is incorrect:

```
sum += quantity*price;
```

Should be

```
var sum = quantity*price;
```

Since you are calculating the line total.

If you are trying to create a GRAND TOTAL for multiple lines you need to do this inside your key press handler and after you calc the line total.

```
       var sum = 0;

       $(".line-total").each(function(){
       sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
       })                

       $('.final span').text(sum);
```

Note that i am using a class on the line total span .line-total and circling all the totals in my checkout

```
        '<div class="container"> ' +    
        '<p class="name"> Item: ' + data.name + '</p>' +
        '<p class="price" data-price="' + data.price + '">Price : ' + data.price + '</p>'+
        '<input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity[]" /><br><br>' +
        '<p class="total" >Total Price  $:<span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p>' +
        '</div>'
```

see new fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tsm6d4zp/3/

Comment: I don't understand how your answer does solve my  question

Comment: If you are trying to allow a user to update a line total then your sum is incorrect. Also you are using keyup, it would be better to use .input()

Comment: Not updating a line total. My line total is working fine and i want my grand sum to be accurate like the line total.

Comment: Unless i am missing something that works, i had to add the missing code to init the checkout with an item.

Comment: Alright the fiddle is explaining what i want but you just displayed one item. i have multiple items. How do i add up the line total to get the grand. Because you code is just for one item

Comment: That is because you have not posted all the working code - If you see my answer above i have explained. You need an entirely new function to total all the lines in the checkout everytime one line is edited. Your code is only totaling line totals, which i fixed.

Comment: I have posted all the code for that side. New function? How do i total all the lines?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tsm6d4zp/3/ i have again updated my ans is now does as you ask.